# Filter Image Collection by Multiple WRS Path/Rows using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

How can I filter an image collection in Google Earth Engine by multiple WRS paths/rows?

This is an example of a filter using one path.row:

```js
var sr2011 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5_SR')
  .filterDate('2011-06-20', '2011-08-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 59))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 18));
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try combining AND and OR filters or, if more complicated, you could look into `ee.Filter.inList`:

```js
var sr2011 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT5_SR')
  .filterDate('2011-06-20', '2011-08-31')
  .filter(ee.Filter.or(
    ee.Filter.and(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 59),         
                  ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 18)),
    ee.Filter.and(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', 60), 
                  ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', 19))))
```

This works but capitals are needed on ee.Filter.Or and ee.Filter.On

Answer (score 0):

For more Points use this tool:

https://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat_acq#convertPathRow

Comment: Can you add some details why, and how? The link might stop working